# Merging JSON object with same KEY using Python

Tags: python, json

I need to merge JSON object with same keys into a single JSON object.
For example,

```
{ 
   "key1" : [
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "hello"
     }],
   "key1" : [
    {
      "id" : 2,
      "name" : "hi"
     }]
}
```

The above JSON data has to be changed like this :

```
{
"key1" :
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "hello"
     },
    {
      "id" : 2,
      "name" : "hi"
     }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging JSON elements with the same keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062942/merging-json-elements-with-the-same-keys)

Comment: Your input is invalid...`dicts` cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: Hi @Rakesh , I am aware that the input is invalid, but I can't do anything about that. That's the reason I'm asking this question .

Comment: @Rakesh no i dont think so that is invalid for detail visit this http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf

Comment: Python dictionaries don't support duplicate keys. One way around is to store lists or sets inside the dictionary.