# Python group JSON Response by ID

Tags: python, json

I call a restAPI via Python and get a JSON Object in Response which looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "userid":1,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T07:00:00.000Z",
      "calculated":false
   },
   {
      "userid":1,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T11:00:00.000Z",
      "calculated":false
   },
   {
      "userid":1,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T12:00:00.000Z",
      "calculated":false
   },
   {
      "userid":1,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T16:00:00.000Z",
      "calculated":false
   },
   {
      "userid":2,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T07:00:00.000Z",
      "calculated":false
   },
   {
      "userid":2,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T11:15:00.000Z",
      "calculated":false
   },
   {
      "userid":2,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T12:00:00.000Z",
      "calculated":false
   },
   {
      "userid":2,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T16:30:00.000Z",
      "calculated":false
   }
]
```

I am struggling with the problem to group those Values means I want to achieve something like this:

```
[
   {
      "userid":1,
      "check_in":[
         "2022-01-10T07:00:00.000Z",
         "2022-01-10T11:00:00.000Z",
         "2022-01-10T12:00:00.000Z",
         "2022-01-10T16:00:00.000Z"
      ],
      "calculated":false
   },
   {
      "userid":2,
      "check_in":[
         "2022-01-10T11:00:00.000Z",
         "...",
         "...."
      ],
      "calculated":false
   }
]
```

Would be great if someone could point me out how to achieve this in python since I usually don´t develop python.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sounds like `pandas` is what you might want.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062942/merging-json-elements-with-the-same-keys) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357405/combine-duplicate-keys-in-json) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used groupby from itertools module to solve this. Groupby the (userid, calculated) pair and the extract the data from the groupings.

```
import json
from itertools import groupby
data = [
   {
      "userid":1,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T07:00:00.000Z",
      "calculated":False
   },
   {
      "userid":1,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T11:00:00.000Z",
      "calculated":False
   },
   {
      "userid":1,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T12:00:00.000Z",
      "calculated":False
   },
   {
      "userid":1,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T16:00:00.000Z",
      "calculated":False
   },
   {
      "userid":2,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T07:00:00.000Z",
      "calculated":False
   },
   {
      "userid":2,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T11:15:00.000Z",
      "calculated":False
   },
   {
      "userid":2,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T12:00:00.000Z",
      "calculated":False
   },
   {
      "userid":2,
      "check_in":"2022-01-10T16:30:00.000Z",
      "calculated":False
   }
]

result = []
key_function = lambda x: (x["userid"], x["calculated"])
data.sort(key = key_function)
for group, checkings in groupby(data, key_function):
        user = {
                "userid": group[0],
                "calculated": group[1],
                "check_in": []
        }
        for check_in in checkings:
                user["check_in"].append(check_in["check_in"])
        result.append(user)

print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
```

Comment: This only works if the data is already sorted by "userid" and "calculated".

Comment: @Tzane I forgot about that part. Updated my answer.